# Changing format of a string

Tags: php

Hello My question is that i will have a textarea which i want to paste the following

```
[{"1173627548":{"methv":"dont know","q1":"-","q2":"-","q3":"U","q4":"-","comm":""}},{"1173627548":{"methv":"dont know","q1":"-","q2":"-","q3":"U","q4":"-","comm":""}}]
```

is there any way i can run a loop which allows me to manipulate the data individually so i  can update this to the database. so the first time i run the loop is get this:

```
{"1173627548":{"methv":"dont know","q1":"-","q2":"-","q3":"U","q4":"-","comm":""}}
```

if possible i want to strip out the {'s and :'s and "s so i am left with the commas and the data. For example:

1173627548,methv,dont know.. etc

sorry if i am unclear with my question in any way.

Comment: Is this JSON data? Then http://www.php.net/json_decode is for you

Comment: Hey you forgot to write -s (hyphens)... Do you want to keep hyphens in your resultant string? It doesn't seem so from the example you've given...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$myhugejson = 'blah...';

$array = json_decode($myhugejson, true);

foreach($array as $sub) {
    print_r($sub);

    echo $thing = $sub[0]['methv'];
    echo $second = $sub[0]['q1'];
}
```

In each iteration, `$sub` should contain your list.

All of this is assuming you're using JSON, which I think that is.

To reference i

Comment: im presuming that $myhugejson is the string i posted?

Comment: hey man sorry for the late reply! but i just tried this and it work!it comes out as: Array ( [1173627548] => Array ( [methv] => dont know [q1] => - [q2] => - [q3] => U [q4] => - [comm] => ) ) Array ( [1173627548] => Array ( [methv] => dont know [q1] => - [q2] => - [q3] => U [q4] => - [comm] => ) ) any idea how i can assign each thing like $s = methv

Comment: You reference it like `$thing = $sub[0]['methv']`

Comment: Dude You are Amazing. one more question so sorry! what can i use to call the number side of things (1173627548)

Comment: PS if i wanted to call q1 is it $thing2 = $sub[1]['q1']?

Comment: I've updated the answer. If this answered it, be sure to tick the green arrow next to my answer.